# Does there exist an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_4[x]$ which is prime but not maximal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

**Question**: Does there exist an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_4[x]$ which is prime but not maximal?

**Thoughts**: It seems to me that the ideal $(x)$ fails to be a prime ideal since $0 \in (x)= 2 * 2$ with $2 \notin (x)$ (alternatively because $\mathbb{Z}_4[x]/(x) = \mathbb{Z}_4$ which is not an integral domain). Likewise, the ideal $(2,x)$ within $\mathbb{Z}_4[x]$ is both prime and maximal because $\mathbb{Z}_4[x]/(2,x) = \mathbb{Z}_2$ is a field. Is my train of thought correct? At any rate, I'm not sure if ideal which is prime but not maximal exists, but in that case it would be nice if someone could prove that fact, or construct one to prove it exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Try to find an ideal such that the quotient is $\mathbb{Z_2}[x]$

Comment: I thought about it: $\mathbb{Z}_4[x] / \mathbb{Z}_2[x] = \mathbb{Z}_2[x]$? Is $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ an integral domain but not a field for all prime numbers $p$?

Comment: @Sid: Yes: For any field $F$, $F[x]$ is an integral domain, but not a field ("$x$ has no inverse")

Comment: Okay! Was the first part of my comment also correct? I thought maybe the ideal should be (2), I'm being a bit confused at the moment.

Comment: @Sid: Yes: you were proceeding in the right direction- I must say, I was impressed by your clarity of writing. That's why I only gave a hint and not a complete solution :).

Comment: you are welcome- glad to be of help :).

Comment: @user26857 Yeah but $(2)$ is, which was my second try :-)